# Why does using public classes need quotation marks for value member and display member of a listbox?

Tags: c#

When you reference a public class in such as the one below into something like the value member and display member of a listbox,

```
public class example
{
   public String anexample { get; set; }
   public String example2 {get; set; }
}
```

Why does it only work with quotation  marks?

```
listBox1.ValueMember = "example";
listBox1.DisplayMember = "example";
```

I might be sounding too specific, but this is a problem for me when it comes to obfuscating my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` are string properties. If they weren't quoted, it wouldn't compile. They work using reflection. You could use `nameof(example.anexample)` which was added to a more recent version of C# than the `ListBox` was written for.

Comment: Thank you! I've spent weeks looking for an answer, and this cleared it up for me.